# ThreadPoolExecutor hangs

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Trying to debug a race condition where one of our application's poller threads never return causing future pollers to never get scheduled. In abstract terms to hide our business logic while capturing the problem, here's what our code path is.

We have to update some state X of resource Y in a remote server. We have a resource manager, which changes the resource state and updates X as a side effect of the change. This manager polls the resource continually and when it believes resource is updated, it uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to do the work. This thread pool executor has a reasonably sized blocking queue but fairly small number of max threads. The hang itself from thread dump happens in invokeAll call (among other things)

We have reasons to believe that the number of core/max threads in this pool executor are busy doing other stuff (more resource state updations, if you will).

Since invokeAll returns us futures which we wait on, the question is does invokeAll hang even if the blocking data structure used by the executor is big enough to take in the work passed in via invokeAll but there are no enough threads available?

Answer (score 3):

As other users have pointed out, without some code (even pseudo-code), and a clearer understanding of what "state *X*" is, and what "resource *Y*" is, it is virtually impossible for anybody here to provide an intelligent answer. In short, you need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Nevertheless, I'll do my best here ;-). And if you do post code and/or provide more info, I'll update my answer accordingly.

From the [Java 7 `ExecutorService#invokeAll` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

**From your description** (and again, I can't tell for sure because of the lack of details), one of your worker threads is hanging. Since you're calling `invokeAll(...)`, the executor is hanging because it's waiting for the hung thread to finish. But it never does. Now, as to why you're getting a hung thread, that's an entirely different issue, and we would definitely need to see some code. HTH.